# Get XML files and save copies of them into a folder using vba

Tags: xml, vba, excel, save

I am new to integrating VBA with XML. I need to get a lot XML files and save copies of them into a folder.

Example xml (s):

```
http://simpsons.org/api/rest/v2/identities/HOMER
http://simpsons.org/api/rest/v2/identities/MARGE
http://simpsons.org/api/rest/v2/identities/BART
http://simpsons.org/api/rest/v2/identities/LISA
http://simpsons.org/api/rest/v2/identities/MAGGIE
...
```

folder example:

```
C:\Users\myPC\Documents
```

Now, I would like to be able to use the base URL:

```
http://simpsons.org/api/rest/v2/identities/
```

I would also like to use a named range "SimpsonsIdentities", which is populated with all the identities I want, to add to the base URL as well as the end of the name of the saved files I will create. To do this I will have to loop through each name in the range "SimpsonsIdentities".

```
SimpsonsIdentities
HOMER
MARGE
BART
LISA
MAGGIE
...
```

I am thinking that the basic structure will be something like this:

```
Sub SaveTheSimpsons ()

Dim n As Long
Dim BaseURL As String
Dim SimpsonsIdentitiesCount As Long
...

For n = 1 To SimpsonsIdentitiesCount
    GET BaseURL & SimpsonsIdentity
    SaveAs C:\Users\myPC\Documents & "\" & SimpsonsIdentity
Next n

End Sub
```

I would greatly appreciate any help. I am not even sure which way the slashes should be going for the file save.